# Should I add index when indexes are greater than RAM in mysql

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.7

`Data_length + index_length` are greater than `innodb_buffer_size`, and I have a huge table where the `select` took longer than 5 minutes. Should I resolve this issue by adding another index on a column, or it will just getting worse?

Here is the table schema:

```
| record | CREATE TABLE `record` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `altitude` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `details` longtext,
  `deviation` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuel_level` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gsm_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `satellite` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `treated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_driver` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_vehicle_device` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ai9y9d52lx1xvtaiv3w0x60a5` (`id_driver`),
  KEY `FK_ilwlg0mt87bxyemx4tov1elni` (`id_vehicle_device`),
  KEY `treated_record` (`treated`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ai9y9d52lx1xvtaiv3w0x60a5` FOREIGN KEY (`id_driver`) REFERENCES `driver` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ilwlg0mt87bxyemx4tov1elni` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vehicle_device`) REFERENCES `vehicle_device` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=129117058 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

here is the `select` :

```
select count(*) from record where datetime between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-30' and id_vehicle_device = 2;
```

and here is the `explain select` :

```
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       

|  1 | SIMPLE      | record | NULL       | ref  | FK_ilwlg0mt87bxyemx4tov1elni | FK_ilwlg0mt87bxyemx4tov1elni | 8       | const | 264902 |    11.11 | Using where
```

This query `SELECT FLOOR(SUM(data_length+index_length)/POWER(1024,2)) InnoDBSizeMB FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';` give me :

```
+--------------+
| InnoDBSizeMB |
+--------------+
|       375462 |
+--------------+
```

while `innodb_log_file_size = 32G`.

Comment: In order to say we'd need more information.  What does your table structure look like?  What is the select statement that is taking a long time? What indexes do you already have?

Comment: Please provide the `SELECT`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Performance improvement may be as simple as adding a composite index.